# css drop down menu links are being pushed right

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a drop down menu, and instead of another UL after a closing LI tag, I'm using a DIV tag instead, because I'm not displaying another unordered list, I'm displaying a login.

Here is a picture of the issue, the link is being pushed over when hovered over.

[image]

If anyone knows a solution, that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Code:s

```css
.menu {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  padding: 1px;
}

.menu nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

.menu nav ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 21px 20px;
}

.menu nav ul li a:hover {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: #333;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 28px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -o-border-radius: 20px;
  -ms-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth .glob-auth-top {
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #00B16A;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth .glob-auth-top header h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth .glob-auth-body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth .glob-auth-body input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 260px;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth .glob-auth-body input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth .glob-auth-body input:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth .glob-auth-body button {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #009157;
  border-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu nav ul li>.glob-auth .glob-auth-body button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.menu nav ul li:hover>.glob-auth {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Login</a>
        <div class="glob-auth">
          <div class="glob-auth-top">
            <header>
              <h1>Login</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
          <div class="glob-auth-body">
            <form method="post">
              <input type="text" name="l_user" placeholder="Enter username" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20">
              <input type="password" name="l_pass" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="120">
              <button name="l_submit">Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Register</a>
        <div class="glob-auth">
          <div class="glob-auth-top">
            <header>
              <h1>Register</h1>
            </header>
          </div>
          <div class="glob-auth-body">
            <form method="post">
              <input type="text" name="l_user" placeholder="Enter username" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20">
              <input type="password" name="l_pass" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="120">
              <button name="l_submit">Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert This:

```
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth {
    position: absolute;
    //Other codes...
}
```

```css
.menu{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    padding: 1px;
}
.menu nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu nav ul li{
    float: left;
}
.menu nav ul li a{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 21px 20px;
}
.menu nav ul li a:hover{
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    color: #333;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth .glob-auth-top{
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #00B16A;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth .glob-auth-top header h1{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fcfcfc;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth .glob-auth-body{
    padding: 10px;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth .glob-auth-body input{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 260px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth .glob-auth-body input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth .glob-auth-body input:nth-child(2){
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth .glob-auth-body button{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #009157;
    border-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fcfcfc;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu nav ul li > .glob-auth .glob-auth-body button:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.menu nav ul li:hover > .glob-auth{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a>
            <div class="glob-auth">
                <div class="glob-auth-top">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Login</h1>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <div class="glob-auth-body">
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="l_user" placeholder="Enter username" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20">
                        <input type="password" name="l_pass" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="120">
                        <button name="l_submit">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a>
            <div class="glob-auth">
                <div class="glob-auth-top">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Register</h1>
                    </header>
                </div>
                <div class="glob-auth-body">
                    <form method="post">
                        <input type="text" name="l_user" placeholder="Enter username" autocomplete="off" maxlength="20">
                        <input type="password" name="l_pass" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off" maxlength="120">
                        <button name="l_submit">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```